# Unbind all keys from mode

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I would like to prevent modes to add any custom keys to emacs.

For example this works for default key map:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") nil)
```

And this works for ensime:

```
(eval-after-load "ensime-mode"
  '(define-key ensime-mode-map (kbd "C-c") nil))
```

But same doesn't work for yas:

```
(eval-after-load "yas-minor-mode"
  '(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c") nil))
```

So in the end it looks for me like this:

[image]

Is it possible to remove all keys from packages/modes?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work for yas" (is the picture supposed to exhibit the problem with yas?  I don't see what makes you think yas is the culprit there).  Also I suspect that it might be much easier to fix your underlying problem in a different way, so you should probably explain a bit what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: @Stefan I mean I still have map available from https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/yasnippet.el#L654 when I press C-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `yas-minor-mode` is not defined in a file named `yas-minor-mode.el` but in the file named `yasnippet.el` so you need

```
(eval-after-load "yasnippet"
  '(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c") nil))
```

You can also use

```
(eval-after-load 'yasnippet
  '(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c") nil))
```

or

```
(add-hook 'yas-minor-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c") nil)))
```

Comment: I thought first argument is a mode/package name, thanks!

Comment: It's a package name yes, but not a mode name.